# SQL Select Max(Date) out of rows with Duplicate Id

Tags: sql, join, duplicates

I have a table like the below sample. I'm trying to get the row of every user having status 0 and if there is a duplicate UserId then get the row with  max(CreatedDate) for that user

**TableA**

```
+----+--------+-------------+--------+
| Id | UserId | CreatedDate | Status |
+----+--------+-------------+--------+
|  1 | a234   | 09/02/2017  |      0 |
|  2 | a234   | 09/03/2017  |      0 |
|  3 | a234   | 09/06/2017  |      1 |
|  4 | a143   | 08/25/2017  |      0 |
+----+--------+-------------+--------+
```

**Expected Output**

```
+----+--------+-------------+--------+
| Id | UserId | CreatedDate | Status |
+----+--------+-------------+--------+
|  2 | a234   | 09/03/2017  |      0 |
|  4 | a143   | 08/25/2017  |      0 |
+----+--------+-------------+--------+
```

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT d.Id, d.UserId,d.CreatedDate,d.Status FROM 
(
    SELECT Id, Max(CreatedDate) as MaxDate  
    FROM TableA
    GROUP BY Id
    HAVING Count(*)>1
) r
INNER JOIN TableA d
ON d.Id=r.Id AND d.CreatedDate=r.MaxDate AND Status=0
```

But I think the condition is wrong which should be like a sequence eg:

> 1st condition Status=0
>
> 2nd Condition If Duplicate UserId exist take Max(CreatedDate) else CreatedDate

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the data you are really using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:-

```
SELECT d.Id, d.UserId,d.CreatedDate,d.Status FROM 
(
    SELECT UserId, Max(CreatedDate) as MaxDate  
    FROM TableA
    WHERE Status = 0
    GROUP BY UserId
) r
INNER JOIN TableA d
ON d.UserId=r.UserId AND d.CreatedDate=r.MaxDate AND Status=0
```

Your `GROUP BY` and `JOIN` needed to be on `UserId` for this to work, and I've moved the filter by `Status=0` to the derived table / subquery.

Comment: Woah! It worked... You are right, I was using Id instead of UserId. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution using subquery in `WHERE`

```
SELECT d.Id, d.UserId, d.CreatedDate,d.Status 
FROM TableA d
WHERE d.Status  = 0 and d.CreatedDate = 
      (
            SELECT MAX(x.CreatedDate)
            FROM TableA x
            WHERE x.Status  = 0 AND x.UserId = d.UserId
      )
```

another solution might be using `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT d.Id, d.UserId, d.CreatedDate,d.Status 
FROM TableA d
WHERE d.Status  = 0 and NOT EXISTS
      (
            SELECT MAX(x.CreatedDate)
            FROM TableA x
            WHERE x.Status  = 0 AND x.UserId = d.UserId AND 
                  x.CreatedDate > d.CreatedDate
      )
```

or `ALL`

```
SELECT d.Id, d.UserId, d.CreatedDate,d.Status 
FROM TableA d
WHERE d.Status  = 0 and d.CreatedDate >= 
      ALL(
            SELECT x.CreatedDate
            FROM TableA x
            WHERE x.Status  = 0 AND x.UserId = d.UserId
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    select
        ID
        , UserID
        , CreatedDate
        , [Status]
    from TableA A
    inner join (
        select 
            max(CreatedDated) [MaxDate]
            , UserID
            , [Status] 
        from TableA 
        where [Status] = 0 
        group by UserID, [Status]
        ) B on A.UserID = B.UserID and A.CreatedDate = B.MaxDate and A.[Status] = B.[Status]
```

I think the reason you were getting results that you didn't expect was your  "having count(*) > 1" would only return duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will find the below SQL to be more efficient and elegant.

```
SELECT Id, UserId, CreatedDate, Status,
MAX (CreatedDate) OVER (PARTITION BY USerId) AS max_CreatedDate
FROM TableA
WHERE Status = 0;
```

Let me know if it works OK for you!

Ted.

Comment: This gives me rows with duplicate UserId and the Max(CreatedDate) is not effective

Comment: I see! I misunderstood your intentions, I thought you wanted to return all IDs with Status = 0.