# How to use multiple max Function in SQL select with left join

Tags: sql, oracle, join, select, group-by

Suppose I have the following three tables:

Table1:

| ID | Value_1 |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | abc |
| 22 | def |
| 33 | xyz |

Table2:

| ID | Date_1 |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 12-Mar-22 |
| 11 | 01-Jan-23 |
| 22 | 19-Dec-22 |
| 22 | 07-Feb-23 |
| 33 | 07-Mar-22 |

Table3:

| ID | Length_1 |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 574 |
| 11 | 1029 |
| 22 | 9220 |
| 33 | 1093 |
| 33 | 876 |

Now, I need an SQL query that would select each ID with Max Lenth_1 and Max Date_1.

Desired output:

| ID | Value_1 | Date_1 | Length_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | abc | 01-Jan-23 | 1029 |
| 22 | def | 07-Feb-23 | 9220 |
| 33 | xyz | 07-Mar-22 | 1093 |

I have used max() fuction to achieve this with left join between 2 tables together, however struggling when I have to use Max () twice with 3 tables. I am relatively new to SQL.

[SQL Select Max(Date) out of rows with Duplicate Id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46082417/sql-select-maxdate-out-of-rows-with-duplicate-id)
  [I tried this for two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46082417/sql-select-maxdate-out-of-rows-with-duplicate-id)

Comment: Simply JOIN, GROUP BY and use MAX().

Comment: Can you please add your tried query rather than adding a link

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Select t1.id, t1.value1, max(t2.date_1) date_1, max(t3.length_1)t3
from table_1 t1
left join table_2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id
left join table_3 t3 on t1.id=t3.id
group by t1.id, t1.value1
order by 1
```

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: This will give `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate before you join the tables:

```sql
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.value_1,
       t2.date_1,
       t3.length_1
FROM   table1 t1
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT id,
                MAX(date_1) AS date_1
         FROM   table2
         GROUP BY id
       ) t2
       ON (t1.id = t2.id)
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT id,
                MAX(length_1) AS length_1
         FROM   table3
         GROUP BY id
       ) t3
       ON (t1.id = t3.id)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Table1 (ID, Value_1) AS
SELECT 11, 'abc' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 22, 'def' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 33, 'xyz' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Table2 (ID, Date_1) AS
SELECT 11, DATE '2022-03-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, DATE '2023-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 22, DATE '2022-12-19' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 22, DATE '2023-02-07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 33, DATE '2022-03-07' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Table3 (ID, Length_1) AS
SELECT 11,  574 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 1029 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 22, 9220 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 33, 1093 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 33,  876 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | VALUE_1 | DATE_1 | LENGTH_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | abc | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 1029 |
| 22 | def | 2023-02-07 00:00:00 | 9220 |
| 33 | xyz | 2022-03-07 00:00:00 | 1093 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Gp1-Lx9m)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use subqueries selecting max values from tables 2 and 3:

```sql
Select      t1.ID, t1.VALUE_1, 
            (Select Max(DATE_1) From Table2 Where ID = t1.ID) "DATE_1",  
            (Select Max(LENGTH_1) From Table3 Where ID = t1.ID) "LENGTH_1"
From        Table1 t1
Order By    t1.ID
```

... another one is to use analytic function with distinct keyword but it could be performance costly with big datasets:

```sql
Select  DISTINCT
            t1.ID, t1.VALUE_1, Max(t2.DATE_1) OVER(Partition By t1.ID) "DATE_1",  Max(t3.LENGTH_1) OVER(Partition By t1.ID) "LENGTH_1"
From        Table1 t1
Inner Join  Table2 t2 ON(t2.ID = t1.ID)
Inner Join  Table3 t3 ON(t3.ID = t1.ID)
Order By    t1.ID
```

... both with your sample data:

```sql
WITH 
    Table1 (ID, VALUE_1) AS
        (
            Select 11, 'abc' From Dual Union All
            Select 22, 'def' From Dual Union All
            Select 33, 'xyz' From Dual
        ),
    Table2 (ID, DATE_1) AS
        (
            Select 11, To_Date('2022-03-12', 'yyyy-mm-dd') From Dual Union All
            Select 11, To_Date('2023-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') From Dual Union All
            Select 22, To_Date('2022-12-19', 'yyyy-mm-dd') From Dual Union All
            Select 22, To_Date('2023-02-07', 'yyyy-mm-dd') From Dual Union All
            Select 33, To_Date('2022-03-07', 'yyyy-mm-dd') From Dual
        ),
    Table3 (ID, LENGTH_1) AS
        (
            Select 11,  574 From Dual Union All
            Select 11, 1029 From Dual Union All
            Select 22, 9220 From Dual Union All
            Select 33, 1093 From Dual Union All
            Select 33,  876 From Dual   
        )
```

results as:

```sql
        ID VALUE_1 DATE_1      LENGTH_1
---------- ------- --------- ----------
        11 abc     01-JAN-23       1029 
        22 def     07-FEB-23       9220 
        33 xyz     07-MAR-22       1093
```